# Swift decoding string JSON fails

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

```
struct APOD: Codable {
    let points: String
    let full_name: String
    let description: String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let product = try! decoder.decode(APOD.self, from: jsonData.data(using: .utf8)!)

print(product.full_name)
```

I have a String called jsonData that comes from: https://www.instagram.com/georgeanisimow/?__a=1. I formatted the file and pasted it into the project just to have something work.

Unfortunately it fails with this error code:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an
>   error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "points", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
>   debugDescription: "No value associated with key
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: \"points\", intValue: nil) (\"points\").",
>   underlyingError: nil))"

I am trying to print the value for "full_name" in the JSON.

Here is the begginng of the JSON:

```
let jsonData ="""    
{  
   "logging_page_id":"profilePage_592027119",
   "show_suggested_profiles":false,
   "graphql":{  
      "user":{  
         "biography":"- Represented by AEFH Talent and CESD Modeling - I travel a lot -",
         "blocked_by_viewer":false,
         "country_block":false,
         "external_url":null,
         "external_url_linkshimmed":null,
         "edge_followed_by":{  
            "count":4571
         },
         "followed_by_viewer":true,
         "edge_follow":{  
            "count":741
         },
         "follows_viewer":true,
         "full_name":"George Anisimow"
      }
   }
}"""
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: There is no key `points` in the root object of the JSON. The link doesn't show anything.

Comment: @vadian Sorry, didn't realize that, Either way, I have the JSON pasted into the project, no fetching data.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the (beginning of the) JSON.

Comment: @vadian Did so just now

Comment: Include `points, full_name, description` keys in the `JSON` you have added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `full_name` with these structs ( I specified only the relevant keys)

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let graphql : Graphql
}

struct Graphql: Decodable {
    let user : User
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let fullName : String
}
```

and decode the data

```
let data = Data(jsonData.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let fullname = result.graphql.user.fullName
    print(fullname)

} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this

First-Method:

```
do {
    let responseData = Data(data.utf8)
    let decodeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Controller.self, from: responseData)

    if (decodeData.ErrorCode! == "0") {
        //Success
    } else {
        //Failure
    }
} catch let jsonErr {
    //Failure
}
```

Second-Method:

```
do {
    if let responseData = response.data, let decodedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
     print(decodedData)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```